# Error adding/editing content after install TinyMCE as add-on in Plone 5

Tags: tinymce, plone

After installing TinyMCE as add-on in plone 5, I got the following error when trying to add or edit content that has rich text field.

```
 Module Products.TinyMCE.browser.browser, line 127, in jsonConfiguration
  Module Products.TinyMCE.utility, line 959, in getConfiguration
  Module Products.CMFPlone.browser.ploneview, line 324, in bodyClass
  Module plone.app.layout.globals.layout, line 143, in bodyClass
AttributeError: 'View' object has no attribute 'getId'

 - Expression: "widget/@@ploneform-render-widget"
 - Filename:   ... form-1.0-py2.7.egg/plone/app/z3cform/templates/macros.pt
 - Location:   (98:81)
 - Source:     ... place="structure widget/@@ploneform-render-widget"/>
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 - Expression: "python:configuration_method(field=field)"
 - Filename:   ... roducts/TinyMCE/skins/tinymce/tinymce_wysiwyg_support.pt
 - Location:   (14:32)
 - Source:     ... uration_json python:configuration_method(field=field);
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 - Arguments:
```

Ps: [complete traceback](http://pastie.org/10106079)

Comment: I was under the impression that Products.TinyMCE was not supported in Plone 5?  TinyMCE (4) in Plone 5 is provided by plone.app.widgets (IIRC).

Comment: @sdupton, good to know that tinymce is provided in plone.app.widgets. However it is said that "In Plone 5, plone.app.widgets is obsolete because it’s merged into plone.app.z3cform."

Comment: you simply don't need Products.TinyMCE in plone5. plone5 ships with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TinyMCE is part of plone.app.widgets and shipped with Plone 5. There is no need to install Products.TinyMCE in Plone 5. Products.TinyMCE is just for Plone 3/4.

Comment: thank you! Do you have some references of how to customize tinymce in plone 5? We are trying to create a plugin that allow us to insert a dexterity content object to tinymce editor.

Comment: As far as I know you have to override (or amend) the TinyMCE pattern in plone.app.widgets. Though, since Plone 5 is not released yet (we are still in beta), we do not have all the documentation yet. I'd suggest to ask your question on https://community.plone.org/.